# Nodejs request.get respond "Web Page Blocked!"

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I used `get()` method of [npm request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to get content of external url. But there are some sites responding "**Web Page Blocked!**" such as http://gourmet.goo.ne.jp/

[image]

It is still ok when I access this site from browser.
Here is a part of code:

```
var url = 'http://gourmet.goo.ne.jp/';
var headers = {};
headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
headers['Referer Policy'] = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
headers['referer'] = url;
var mod_request = require('request');
var req = mod_request.get({ uri: url, encoding: 'binary', headers: headers }, function(err, res, body) {  
   var result = res.body; // res.body contain error page when url is http://gourmet.goo.ne.jp/
   // Process content here
});
```

Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: please check your firewall settings..because we are also using same firewall and it stucks with some of the node modules

Comment: @AtulAgrawal Current, I've found only this site which returned block page. Other sites are still ok from request.get(). Another side, I can access this site from browser too.

Answer (score 3):

They may detect your making the request using a script, so they want to block you.

One very common way to bypass that is to change the `User Agent`, simulating a browser:

```
var url = 'http://gourmet.goo.ne.jp/';
var headers = {};
headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
headers['Referer Policy'] = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
headers['referer'] = url;
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"

var mod_request = require('request');
var req = mod_request.get({ uri: url, encoding: 'binary', headers: headers }, function(err, res, body) {  
   var result = res.body; // res.body contain error page when url is http://gourmet.goo.ne.jp/
   // Process content here
});
```

For the initial request, what matters is the request headers. So, try to copy the request headers and put them in your script and then remove the ones that are not needed, keeping the minimal set of headers you really need.

Comment: Thanks you so much! But I tried and it could not solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have one but I still can access this site from my browser.

Comment: @GSP It could be that the browser uses a proxy or so.

Comment: My browser has set proxy too. And I tried to remove proxy but it can not help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to set header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] =  '*'

headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks you so much! But I tried and it could not solve the issue.

Comment: I still can access this site from my browser despite of including proxy setting

Comment: am also using request module to get data from different site .  am not setting any kind of header in my request. just try this with out setting headers. request({method: 'GET', url: "your url"},
     function (error, response, body) {
                if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    return;
                }

                var data = JSON.parse(body.toString());
            });